# Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux containers

Tags: sql-server, authentication, active-directory, containers

I have  a problem and hope someone can help me. I have SQL Server as docker container. I want our developers able to login in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) using their Active Directory users. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-containers-ad-auth-adutil-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver15) procedures which was Microsoft Doc page but it didn't work. The log file in container shows about error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.52]
>
> Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.
> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090304, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed.
> Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating system error code indicates the cause of failure. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted [CLIENT: 192.168.1.52]

My container run successfully and I can connect to it using sa user but, I can't login using Windows Authentication.
This is my docker run command:

```
# docker run -itd -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<pass>" -p 1433:1433 --name msdb \
--user root \
-v /root/mssql:/var/opt/mssql/ \
-v /root/mssql/krb5.conf:/etc/krb5.conf \
--dns-search <full domain> \
--dns 192.168.1.49 \
--add-host <dc.mydomain>:192.168.1.49 \
--add-host <mydomain>:192.168.1.49 \
--add-host <my domain.com>:192.168.1.49 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

Also, I checked this [checklists](https://mssqlwiki.com/tag/sspi-handshake-failed-with-error-code-0x80090304-while-establishing-a-connection-with-integrated-security-the-connection-has-been-closed/) but the problem didn't resolve and I got the same error again.

I hope some one can help me how can I resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Is your client machine running SSMS joined to the domain?  If not then are you using Runas to start SSMS so that it has domain context?

Comment: Does the SQL error log have any entries regarding kerberos and the SPN? Can you post the lines from the log?

Comment: I'd also try the debugging mentioned at https://bobsql.com/sql-server-on-linux-kerberos-troubleshooting-hints-and-tips-and-hard-code-debugging/

Answer (score -1):

@Martin Cairry, Yes, client is windows 10 and its joined the domain, ssms verion is 18.5. all users have domain admin privilege. Also when I login to ssms with sa user, I can add my domain user in login section but it can't login using windows authentication.